# Determining Vector points on a circle

Tags: vector, trigonometry, geometry, points

I have a problem it is like trig and pre calc. We are given vector points for OA which is (6 0) and vector OB (-6 0) and OC (5 root11) and they are all points on a circle with a radius of 6. How exactly do you determine or show that these points lie on the circle?

Comment: Are you asking for a mathematical or programmatic method (what language)? Note that only the latter is on-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

For any three points which are not mutually co-linear, there is a point equidistant from each member of the set. Finding this point given three arbitrary points (and not given the radius) is a much more informative project if you're learning trigonometry.

In your example, the solution is simple: x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = r<sup>2</sup>. Each of the points you provided have values such that the sum of their squares equals 36, as expected for a circle of radius 6. Your problem is especially easy because the circle in question is already centered on the origin.