# Get n equidistant Values in a Quarter Circle Curve

Tags: r

## What I've got

I'm setting up a scoring model for a Q&A-system and I'm implementing different score-distributions based on a scale from 0 to a given maximum value considering n cases.
For instance, I managed to create a log (ln) curve as follows:

```
n_cases <- 5
val_max <- 10
val_step <- val_max/n_cases

plot(
  log(exp(val_max))*n_cases/c(1:n_cases) * (val_step/(n_cases-1)*(c(1:n_cases)-1)) / val_step
)
```

[image]

## What I'm trying to do

However, now I'm trying to figure out how to get those values for a quarter circle such as in the log-example from above. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40285988/8757228) gives me an idea how to do it, but I didn't manage to get what I want.

This is what I've got currently, without an idea where to put the maximum value as trial & error didn't really give me a solution either:

```
plot(
  exp(pi * 1i * seq(0, 2, length.out = n_cases+1)[-1])
)
```

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?:

```
n_cases <- 5
val_max <- 5
phi <- seq(pi/2, pi, length.out = n_cases)

x = val_max + val_max*cos(phi)
y = val_max*sin(phi)

plot(x, y)
```

[image]

**Edit:**

> All I want is a vector of indizes between 0 and a given max value
>   raising in a quarter-circle fashion.

Either you have constant x-distances or constant angle-distances:

```
x <- 0:5
r <- 5
y <- rev(sqrt(r^2-x^2))

plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: Almost! It's still not a quarter circle as the values don't have the same distances.

Comment: Yes, that's it. However, the plot was just for visualization. What I still need is one value per index, so that I can use them in my model.

Comment: To create equidistant points spread on an integer index and a fixed y-maximum you'll need to use a line not a circle.

Comment: Ok, then I might have formulated my question wrong. All I want is a vector of indizes between 0 and a given max value raising in a quarter-circle fashion.

Comment: Ok thank you! It isn't really what I expected, but it solved the question. At least now I know what I want. Thanks!

Comment: The scenario you were asking for (constant x-distance and constant angle-distance) can't be realized with a circle equation.

Comment: You're right. That's probably why my brain wasn't able to come up with a meaningful solution prior to asking the question.